# Display block on homepage depending on value in user profile field?

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm currently displaying a block on my D7 site' homepage.

Now I've a requirement to display that block only if the logged in user has a specific value in their profile.

I know it can be done using php evaluation by navigating to the bottom of the block and then click (Pages > Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE ) but have no experience in writing php scripts.

Can anyone help with this please.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
global $user;


 If($user->your_profile_field_value == 'requiredvalue') {
    Return true;
    }
    Else {
    Return false;
    }
```

Comment: thank you @Muhammad Tanweer but how do I get about hiding/showing a block on homepage when block id is lets say '12345'. I've very little experience with php. thanks